# Whats the difference between OpenSSL and Certbot?

Tags: openssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have generated a certificate using Certbot from Letsencrypt. Is Certbot an alternate for OpenSSL or will Certbot uses OpenSSL to generate certificates?

Comment: In addition to @datenwolf's answer, Cerbot manages the issuance (creation) of an SSL X.509 certificate that provides identity information (like your driver's license) to a software application such as the Apache webserver. OpenSSL is a library of software that applications like Apache use to load the SSL certificate and encrypt network communications.

Comment: Thank you Hanley for simpler explanation

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL is a library that implements the TLS protocol and infrastructure on the network level, together with an assortment of utilities. OpenSSL is used to actually enable programs (servers, clients) to create secured connections.

Certbot is a tool that automates the generation of keys and certificates using the ACME protocol.